# Need logic for this Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in Sql Please guide me. I have two tables 1) tblEmploee & 2) tblAgeGroup

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to achieve the AgeGroupName to the tblEmploee table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Solution #1*** -

```
SELECT e.*, a.AgeGroupName 
FROM dbo.tblEmploee e
JOIN dbo.tblAgeGroup a ON e.EmpAge BETWEEN a.AgeGroupMinAge AND a.AgeGroupMaxAge
```

***Solution #2*** -

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblEmploee e
OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 a.AgeGroupName 
     FROM dbo.tblAgeGroup a
     WHERE e.EmpAge BETWEEN a.AgeGroupMinAge AND a.AgeGroupMaxAge 
) a
```

***Solution #3*** -

```
SELECT e.*, AgeGroupName = (
     SELECT a.AgeGroupName 
     FROM dbo.tblAgeGroup a
     WHERE e.EmpAge BETWEEN a.AgeGroupMinAge AND a.AgeGroupMaxAge
) 
FROM dbo.tblEmploee e
```

Comment: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae0df/5)** I was trying the same logic as Solution #1. But you were Quicker.